# Refresh partial view using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This partial view is used to list cart-items:

```
<ul class="cart-dropdown">
    <li>
        <div class="cart-items cart-caption">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var i in Model.CartItems)
                {
                    <li id="list-item-@i.item.ItemID">
                        <div class="container-fluid item-wrap" style="position: relative">
                            <div class="item-remove">
                                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink"
                                   data-id="@i.RecordID" data-itemid="@i.item.ItemID">
                                    x
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 item-img">
                                <div class="row-cart">
                                    <img alt="" id="cartImg" height="71" width="75" src="@i.item.ImageUrl">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 item-info">
                                <div class="row-cart">
                                    <div class="brand-name">
                                        <a href="#" class="brandName">
                                            @i.item.BrandName
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-name">
                                        <a href="#" class="productName">
                                            @i.item.ItemName
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-qty">
                                        <p class="productQTY" id="item-count-@i.item.ItemID">
                                            @i.Count x @i.item.ItemPrice
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 price-info">
                                <div class="row-cart" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="row-mrp">
                                            <span class="cartItemPrice" id="item-total-@i.item.ItemID">
                                                Rs @(@i.Count * @i.item.ItemPrice)
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row-cart sub-cost" style="background: #fff; margin-left: -10px; margin-right: 0">
                <p>
                    Sub Total :
                    <span style="float: right">
                        Rs
                        <span class="ng-binding"></span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Delivery Charge :
                    <span qa="delChargeMB" style="float: right">Free</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row-cart cart-chkout-btn">
                <button type="button">View Basket &amp; Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Above partial view is rendered when user clicks on "My cart" button. I need to allow customers to remove any cart-item they like by clicking a 'remove' button inside _cartDetails.cshtml. This jQuery code is being used to accomplish this task:

```
$(function () {
    $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
        var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var itemID = $(this).attr("data-itemid");
        if (recordToDelete != '') {
            $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete, "itemID": itemID },
                function (data) {
                    if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                        $('#list-item-' + recordToDelete).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#item-count-' + recordToDelete).text(data.ItemCount + " x " + data.ItemPrice);
                        $('#item-total-' + recordToDelete).text(data.ItemCount * data.ItemPrice);
                    }
                    $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                    $(".confirmItemCart").show();
                    $(".confirmItemCart").addClass("collapsed");
                    $('.confirmItemCart').delay(30000).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                });
        }
    })
});
```

**Controller:** (UPDATED)

```
    public ActionResult cartDropDown()
        {
              return RedirectToAction("cartDropDownChild");
        }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult cartDropDownChild()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        // Set up list of cart items with total value
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            ItemCount = cart.GetCount(),
            Message = Server.HtmlEncode("There are no items in your cart. Continue shopping.")
        };
        foreach (var item in viewModel.CartItems)
        {
            item.item = db.Items.Single(i => i.ItemID == item.ItemID);
        }
        return PartialView("_cartDetails", viewModel);
    }
```

This code is successfully removing items from the cart-items list but not updating the partial view (_cartDetails.cshtml). In debug mode, I've checked the values for the (`data`) which is returned from the ajax call and all values are correct. It is just the binding of those values with the _cartDetails html elements that is not working. Maybe I'm missing out something. Someone please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on success callback function use $('yourcartDetailsDiv.').load('_cartDetails URL');

Comment: this will refresh your cart details div with latest items in your cart

Comment: Is there a comma between `'_cartDetails URL'` (these two)?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @MannanBahelim that would result in multiple ajax call for each item removed from cart (one to remove another to load the cart UI after removing data). Imagine the server request getting doubled when the server is under load. Possible performance issue.

Comment: @Rahatur that's right but how do you load updated partial view ? as per your answer each remove call your partial view. am i right  ?

Comment: is this right? (`$('cart-dropdown').load('_cartDetails /ShoppingCart/cartDropDown');`)

Comment: $('cart-dropdown').load('@Url.Action('cartDropDown','ShoppingCart')');

Comment: @MannanBahelim In my answer you can see that there is only one request to the server which deletes data and reloads the cart UI. `$('cart-dropdown').load('_cartDetails /ShoppingCart/cartDropDown');` does not delete data. To delete the data you have to make another ajax request which is not right.

Comment: @MannanBahelim - there are two syntax errors in the last code statement you suggested. here is an screenshot (https://ibb.co/HTBx0jL)

Comment: @MR I did not suggest that option. However you have to wrap string in double quotes in Dotnet not single quote. When you start codes with `@` in cshtml page that would be rendered on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a system design related issues. Partial view gets rendered when the page loads.

When you are removing an item why don't you post to a child action which would render the same partial view and return the html. Then you can put the html in place. You do not need to handle the list-item, cart-total, cart-status etc. manually.

Add the `[ChildActionOnly]` filter to the action that renders the cart information section.

Then in the action: `return PartialView("_cartDetails");`

For example:

Move the logic from `cartDropDown()` function to a private function which will return a `viewModel` object. Then call that private function from both `cartDropDown()` and also in `RemoveFromCart` action (after deleting the data).

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult cartDropDown()
{
    return PartialView("_cartDetails", preparecartDropDown(this.HttpContext));
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(...)
{
    //Delete data
    return PartialView("_cartDetails", preparecartDropDown(this.HttpContext));
}

private ShoppingCartViewModel preparecartDropDown(HttpContext context)
{
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(context);
    var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
        CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
        ItemCount = cart.GetCount(),
        Message = Server.HtmlEncode("There are no items in your cart. Continue shopping.")
    };
    foreach (var item in viewModel.CartItems)
    {
        item.item = db.Items.Single(i => i.ItemID == item.ItemID);
    }

    return viewModel;
}
```

Comment: I've just updated my question with the controller code. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes. Move the logic from `cartDropDown()` function to a private function which will return a `viewModel` object. Then call that private function from both `cartDropDown()` and also in `RemoveFromCart` action (after deleting the data).

Comment: I'm sorry `cartDropDown()` in the controller isn't firing. I have a debug point set on its starting curly brace - while checking a debugger point on the button click of "MyCart" button inside browser Debugger. Browser debugger is firing ajax.request to the controller `(
            $.post("/ShoppingCart/cartDropDown",
                function (data) {
                    $('.cart-skeleton').replaceWith(data);
                    $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
                })
        });` but this call isn't reaching controller action (`cartDropDown`).

Comment: This is very initial ajax request to load all the cart-items into the partial view. This has stopped working now.

Comment: After reverting thing back to original, following issue has started : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107656/partialview-not-rendering

Comment: Is your javascript receiving the html in the `function (data) {`? If it is then put the html in the parent element of `<ul class="cart-dropdown">`

Comment: Obviously this one. If you can resolve the issue with the other question you still need to add the output to the UI.