# PartialView not rendering

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a `Partial View` using jQuery as:

```
$("#cartLi")
    .click(function () {
        $.post("/ShoppingCart/cartDropDown",
            function (data) {
                $('.cart-skeleton').replaceWith(data);
                $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
            })
    });
```

This code successfully fires following action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult cartDropDown()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            ItemCount = cart.GetCount(),
            Message = Server.HtmlEncode("There are no items in your cart. Continue shopping.")
        };
        foreach (var item in viewModel.CartItems)
        {
            item.item = db.Items.Single(i => i.ItemID == item.ItemID);
        }
        return PartialView("_cartDetails", viewModel);
    }
```

This code runs successfully till the very last line (`return PartialView("_cartDetails", viewModel);`) and then the last closing brace - and then breaks without throwing any errors.

Not sure why this strange behavior.

Comment: Hi! What does the action actually return? Does it return the html or not? It might be the view is not found. Examine the response returned by the server.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Could you share your file structure (where is _cartDetails view?)

Comment: @pkmiec - https://ibb.co/Y7mT0P4

Comment: If you get internal server error, your application is crashing. Debug and see what is the actual error.

Comment: Also denote the action as a Child Action - `[ChildActionOnly]`